# How to add Child and Parent items programmatically [ExpandableRecyclerView]?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Acutally i'm trying to implement in my app [this](https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view) Expandable Recycler View.
So i made an project a part for make some test and just after i get how it's work impelent it in my app but i'm having some issues.

I've used [this](https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view/tree/master/sample/src/main/java/com/thoughtbot/expandablerecyclerview/sample) classe's from the ERV github for build by app and i've added 2 `EditText` in the layout and 2 `buttons`, so that **i would archive it if i write something in "GENRE" `edittext` and i press button ADD GENRE there will be added in `RecyclerView` an Item and if i put something in `EditText` Artist and i'll press ADD ARTIST i want that it will be added to the last added GENRE item in the `RecyclerView`.**

Here is my code from my MainActivity.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public GenreAdapter adapter;

    List<Genre> parent;
    EditText artistTXT;
    EditText genreTXT;
    List<Artist> child;
    Button addART;
    Button addGENR;

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        artistTXT = findViewById(R.id.ArtistTXT);
        genreTXT = findViewById(R.id.GenreTXT);

        addART = findViewById(R.id.AddArtist);
        addGENR = findViewById(R.id.AddGenre);



        child = new ArrayList<>();
        parent = new ArrayList<>();

        addART.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                adapter.addChild(new Artist(artistTXT.getText().toString()));

            }
        });


        addGENR.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            adapter.addGroup(new Genre(genreTXT.getText().toString(),null));

            }
        });


        Button clear = findViewById(R.id.toggle_button);
        clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



            }
        });

        BuildRecyclerView();

    }

    public void BuildRecyclerView(){
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        GenreAdapter adapter = new GenreAdapter(parent,this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        adapter.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        adapter.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

}
```

Here is my Adapter code

public class GenreAdapter extends ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter {

```
Context context ;
LayoutInflater inflater ;
List<Genre> genres;

public GenreAdapter(List<? extends ExpandableGroup> groups, Context context) {
    super(groups);
    this.context = context ;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public GenreViewHolder onCreateGroupViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_genre, parent, false);
    return new GenreViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public ArtistViewHolder onCreateChildViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_artist, parent, false);
    return new ArtistViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindChildViewHolder(ArtistViewHolder holder, int flatPosition,
                                  ExpandableGroup group, int childIndex) {

    final Artist artist = (Artist) group.getItems().get(childIndex);
    holder.setArtistName(artist.getName());
}

@Override
public void onBindGroupViewHolder(GenreViewHolder holder, int flatPosition,
                                  ExpandableGroup group) {

    holder.setGenreTitle(group);
}


public void addChild(Artist child){
    // I assume the 'groups' list is accessible in your Adapter
    Genre group = genres.get(genres.size());
    group.getItems().add(child);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addGroup(Genre group){
    genres.add(group);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This answer doesn't work, see edit below**

You have a list of Group containing Child.

So if you want to add a Child to the last existing Group just do (in your Adapter):

```
public void addChild(YourChildType child){
    // I assume the 'groups' list is accessible in your Adapter
    // Retrieve the last group (it's a basic implementation, you may want to check if the list is not empty to prevent an OutOfBoundsException)
    GroupType group = groups.get(groups.size());
    group.getItems().add(child);
    notifyDataSetChanged(); 
}
```

If you want to add a new group:

```
public void addGroup(GroupType group){
   groups.add(group);
   notifyDataSetChanged(
}
```

**EDIT: updated answer**

It turned out it's not possible to change the dataset (yet) once the adapter has been created ([see the response from the author here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view/issues/27))

So you need to store your list of `Genre` in `MainActivity`. Every time you want to update the list you should do:

```
List<Genre> mGenres;
GenreAdapter mAdapter;

public void addGenre(Genre genre){ 
    mGenres.add(genre); 
    mAdapter = new GenreAdapter(genres, ...); 
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter); 
}

public void removeGenre(Genre genre){ 
    mGenres.remove(genre); 
    mAdapter = new GenreAdapter(genres, ...); 
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter); 
}
```

Comment: By adding addChild in my Adapter i'm getting an error, i've added the code in the question can you check it?

Comment: "There is no default constructor available in 'com.thoughtbot...)" i've added it in my Question

Comment: it's because it should be `public void addChild`. I missed the `void` so addChild is considered as a constructor. i've updated my answer

Comment: I've updated my MainActivity with the addChild and addGroup but when i'm trying to add the Group the app Crash with "addGroup, attempt to add method on a null object reference" :l

Comment: It's because `List<Genre> genres;` is never set. Do `final List<Genre> genres;` and set it in the constructor `genres = groups`. But if `groups` is directly accessible from your adapter you don't need to create `genres`. Just use `groups` directly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174151/discussion-between-johnkarry-and-eselfar).